# Differentiation + integration: how to solve for acceleration and displacement given a specific velocity time graph?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification, problem-solving

**The velocity-time graph shown below is for a particle moving in a straight line, from rest at A, through B to C and then back to rest at B.**

I have a few questions below regarding this velocity-time graph that I am unsure how to solve, any hints would be much appreciated!

[image]

My attempts so far:

> *What is the acceleration of the particle 13 seconds after leaving A?*

I know that differentiating velocity with respect to time gives acceleration - however I am unsure of how to apply this in the context of a graph. I'm also thinking I can apply this formula that I found where:

acceleration ($m/s^2$) = change in velocity ($m/s$) ÷ time taken ($s$)

Using the formula I got: $(10+7) ÷ 13 = 1.3077$ - but this is wrong. The correct answer is $-2.5m/s^2$ - I don't know how to get there though.

> *What is the particle's displacement from A 28 seconds after leaving A?*

I think I have confused this with distance in the next question - the answer for **displacement** given is $85$m but how do you get there?

> *How far does the particle move in the first 28 seconds?*

Distance is given from area under the given curve (from $0$ to $28$ seconds)

So I've added the area like so:

$(5 \times 10)/2 = 25$

$7 \times 10 = 70$

$(4 \times 10)/2 = 20$

$(12 \times 5)/2 = 30$

$25 + 70 + 20 + 30 = 145$m

This is from a Year 12 Methods textbook.

Thanks very much in advance for any tips!

Comment: About the first question: Note that when talking about acceleration, usually what is meant is **instantaneous** acceleration. In this case, the instantaneous acceleration at $t=13~\text{s}$ is so that it's constant in the time interval $t=12 \ldots 15$. Basically, what has happened before that, has absolutely no significance. Only the time interval $t=12 \ldots 15$ matters in the first calculation. Is this clear to you?

Comment: @MattiP. - Yes! I see...so it would be $-10/4 = -2.5m/s^2$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question:**

acceleration (m/s2) = change in velocity (m/s) ÷ time taken (s)

here calculate a for 12 to 16 seconds.

for that

> a=dv/dt
>
> ```
> =0-10/16-12
> =-2.5 m/s2
> ```

**Second Question:**

In v/t graph you can find displacement by calculating the area of the graph.
Because displacement equal to velocity into total taken time.

we can divide this graph into four part:

a1 = 0 to 5 s

a2 = 5 to 12 s

a3 = 12 to 16 s

a4 = 16 to 28 s

```
a1 = 5*10/2
   =25m

a2 = 7*10
   = 70m

a3 = 4*10/2
   = 20m

a4 = 12*(-5)/2
   = -30m

Total displacement = Total aria
                   = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4
                   = 25 + 70 + 20 -30
                   = 85m
```